# How to populate a calendar with data

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

In my Java Spring Boot project I am wanting to implement a date picker where the user can click on the calendar icon and then pick a date to rent the session in advance. Ive never done this before so I don't know what the best way would be to implement this or what type of calendar would be best. My front end just consists of Thymeleaf so no front-end framework. I am also using MySQL to hold my sessions.

How would I go about populating the calendar with my sessions so the users can book sessions in advance?

I'm not necessarily looking for the answer because I'm sure its going to be a long one but I'm mainly looking for the right resources. At this point I don't even know the right questions to ask google.

This is my User entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
         
        @Column(name="email")
        private String email;
         
        @Column(name="password")
        private String password;
         
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
         
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
        
        @Column(name = "user_name")
        private String username;
         
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
                  )
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

This is my Session entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="session")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Session {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="time")
    private String time;
    
    @Column(name="status")
    private boolean status;
    
    @Column(name="side")
    private String side;
```

Here is my Session schema:

```
ID     TIME       STATUS   SIDE
'1',  '5:30 AM',   '1',    'A'
'2',  '7:00 AM',   '1',    'A'
'3',  '8:00 AM',   '1',    'A'
'4',  '10:00 AM',  '1',    'A'
'5',  '11:30 AM',  '1',    'A'
'6',  '1:00 PM',   '1',    'A'
'7',  '2:30 PM',   '1',    'A'
'8',  '4:00 PM',   '1',    'A'
'9',  '5:30 PM',   '1',    'A'
'10', '7:00 PM',   '1',    'A'
'11', '8:30 PM',   '1',    'A'
'12', '6:00 AM',   '1',    'B'
'13', '7:30 AM',   '1',    'B'
'14', '9:00 AM',   '1',    'B'
'15', '10:30 AM',  '1',    'B'
'16', '12:00 AM',  '1',    'B'
'17', '1:30 PM',   '1',    'B'
'18', '3:00 PM',   '1',    'B'
'19', '4:30 PM',   '1',    'B'
'20', '6:00 PM',   '1',    'B'
'21', '7:30 PM',   '1',    'B'
'22', '9:00 PM',   '1',    'B'
```

Comment: I suggest you simplify that first paragraph to the minimum amount of info needed to show your issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the advice! do you have any ideas for my problem?

Comment: The problem is quite general, not-concrete, not a problem actually, but a feature request. You want to prefill a calendar, what kind of calendar? Front end? If so, which techonology? Or is it a rest service? If so what are the schemas? What have you tried so far? Any concrete problem trying to implement any kind of solution? That kind of things.

Comment: @gmanjon Thanks for the comment. I will edit my question to make it more clear as to what I am asking for!